# Nginx proxy_pass all url parameters

Tags: nginx

I want to proxy requests like these:
`http://myproxy.com/api/folder1/result1?test=1` 
, `http://myproxy.com/api/folder3447/something?var=one`

to the equivalent destinations: `http://destination.com/folder1/result1?test=1` and `http://destination.com/folder3447/something?var=one`, practically only the domain changes and all subfolders and params are preserved

location in config looks like:

```
location ~* ^/api/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://destination.com/$1$is_args$args;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to simplify your configuration slightly:

```
location /api/ {
    // Note the slash at end, which with the above location block
    // will replace "/api/" with "/". This will not work with regex
    // locations
    proxy_pass http://destination.com/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```