# NGINX serve content on same url without redirecting

Tags: nginx

I have an app that used to get data from my website on this URL -

```
example.com/android/android_script.php?table=something&content=otherthing
```

My website was built with vanilla PHP and jquery on apache2.
I remade my website with nuxt and laravel on NGINX. I set a /api route for backend connection. I can't change my URL in My Android app so I'm trying to serve content on the same URL.
I am redirecting that URL in Nginx like this -

```
rewrite ^/android/android_script3.php$ /api/android permanent;
//it changes 
//example.com/android/android_script.php?table=something&content=otherthing
//to 
//example.com/api/android?table=something&content=otherthing
```

It works in the browser but when I open the app, data loading not working in-app.
Now I want to serve that same content on the same URL without redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used proxy pass.

```
location = /android/android_script.php {
             proxy_pass https://example.com/api/android;
             proxy_redirect off;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Connection "";
             proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             }
```

Comment: got answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38595555/8176783